# Size mismatch in mongodb backup and restore

Tags: mongodb, restore, database-backups

I did a MongoDB backup and restore using the document in the following link.

[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)

But after I restore the data there is a size mismatch in the two DBs.
In production DB where I took the backup XXX, DB size is 0.007GB But after I restore the backup, the restored XXX DB size is 0.005GB. I tried with studio 3T also but the same issue was there. Need help on this.

Comment: Are you asking for help or offering job? The only message in the question is you face **a** problem you cannot solve. It sounds more like a job spec than a SO question. You've been around for some times and know how it works. Be precise, what kind of help you expect?

Comment: Sorry, it does not explain much what kind of help you expect. It won't harm to explain how you calculate DB size. Do you get it from  OS, from db.stats()? The later reports several sizes, which one you are talking about? Even better add the result of db.stats() before and after.

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm referring to the values I get when I run the show databases command

Comment: ok, a little progress. `show dbs` returns "sizeOnDisk". I would strongly recommend to explicitly write what kind of help you need with that. I don't see how shrieked file size is a problem tbh.

Comment: @AlexBlex I opened two DBs separately on the mongo DB compass and check, size mismatch comes from the total index size all other size values are the same in both DBs